# traverse the std::map with less than comparison between iterators

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, traversal

When I'd like to traverse a map in C++, we may use the following technique:

```
for (auto i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); i++)
{    ...    ... }
```

Why cannot we use the following instead:

```
for (auto i = m.begin(); i < m.end(); i++)
{    ...    ... }
```

My guess is because the elements in an associative container are not stored in sequential order like sequential containers, is that right?

Comment: It's not about associativity. It's about not being sequential. It's not necessarily the same

Comment: for range avoids the issue completely :) `for (/*const*/ auto& p : m) {..}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comparison operator `<` requires [random access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

`map` only provides Bidirectional iterators. The reason is that you cannot say with just such an iterator if another iterator is before or after in constant time (yes, they are not one after the other in memory).

As `!=` is valid for all types of iterators, use it instead of the `<` version. It's portable if you change the container type.

Comment: *"in constant time"*. Even in linear time, btw, as you don't have bounds.

Comment: @Jarod42 That's true. Not sure about the constraints for the comparison operator for random access iterators? Is it constant or linear (thinking about deque)?

Comment: I don't see complexity constraint on that, but doesn't `r += n` constant allow `b - a` constant too ?

Comment: @Jarod42 agreed, that's why I thought saying constant time. Not sure if I should add the note about linear time.

Comment: C++17 [iterator.requirements.general]/10: "All the categories of iterators require only those functions that are realizable for a given category in constant time (amortized). Therefore, requirement tables for the iterators do not have a complexity column."